# reactjs map un objeto

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo un objeto users que al llamarlo me devuelve esto:

```
console.log(users)
> Array(2)
 0: {id: 1, username: 'Agustin', vote: 'Waiting for vote...'}
> 1: {id: 2, username: 'Elias', vote: 'Waiting for vote...'} length: 2
> [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

me gustaria realizarle un map para renderizar un componente para cada persona de esta manera

```
<Person name={username} vote={vote}>
```

Como puedo hacer? ya probe de todas las maneras posibles y no hay resultado

**Edit:**
Users viene desde el *backend*

```
  io.on("connection", async (socket)=> {
  console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);
  let personas=await pool.query("select * from people");
  var respuestaJson=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(personas))

  socket.emit('send-data',respuestaJson);
```

**Frontend**

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState({})
     

      useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("send-data", (data) => {
         
          setUsers(data)
    
          
         
        });
    
      }, [socket]);
```

Comment: Ahi lo agregue.

Comment: Ahi agregue en el front cuando trae la data del back. despues en el return no tengo nada aun por que no supe hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando [hook de efecto](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) podrías hacerlo así:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

export default function MiComponente(props) {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIOClient('https://...');
    socket.on("send-data", (data) => {
      setUsers(data)
    });
  }, []);

  // Si no es un arreglo
  if (!Array.isArray(users)) {
    return 'Cargando...';
  }

  // Si no hay usuarios
  if (users.length === 0) {
    return 'No hay usuarios';
  }
  
  // Si hay usuarios
  return users.map(data => {
    return <Person name={data.username} vote={data.vote}>
  });
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! funciono a la perfeccion